# Text before space in Access query

Tags: ms-access

How would I get the text in a string before a space - and avoid an error if there is no space in the string?

For example, if I have a FirstName field with names that looks like this:

- John S
- Sally Q
- Thomas R
- Robert
- Mary J

I want the field in the query to return:

- John
- Sally
- Thomas
- Robert
- Mary

I tried the following field in my query but it is still returning the space and character after the space:

```
FName: Left([FirstName],IIf(Len(InStr([FirstName]," ")=0),Len([FirstName]),InStr([FirstName]," ")-1))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

`Left(FirstName, IIf(InStr(FirstName, " ")=0, Len(FirstName), InStr(FirstName," ")-1))`

Or

`IIf(InStr(FirstName, " "), Left(FirstName, InStr(FirstName, " ")-1), FirstName)`

This assumes all entries follow the example patterns provided, and not something like: Mary Jo R. Gets complicated if you want Mary Jo.

Comment: Thank you @June7!  Both of those worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

`Left([First Name], IIf((InStrRev([First Name], " ", -1)-1)<= 0, Len([First Name]), InStrRev([First Name], " ", -1)-1))`

Comment: Thanks, @Pflipper, your solution worked as well.  Thanks again!